# Exoplayer not playing video, Audio sink error

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

Exoplayer not playing video, playing only audio second time.

```
@Composable
fun VideoLayout(videoUrl: String?, muted: Boolean = false) {

    if (videoUrl == null)
        return

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val videoPlayer = VideoPlayer.getInstance()
    val exoPlayer = videoPlayer.getExoplayer(context)
    val exoPlayerView = getStyledPlayerView(context, exoPlayer)

    videoPlayer.playVideo(videoUrl)
    exoPlayerView.useController = false

    if (muted)
        exoPlayer.volume = 0f

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Black, shape = RectangleShape),
        factory = { exoPlayerView }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun getStyledPlayerView(
    context: Context,
    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
) = remember {

    StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
        player = exoPlayer
        resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
    }
}



  fun playVideo(url: String) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
        player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player?.prepare()
        player?.play()
    }

    fun release() {
        player?.let {
            player?.stop()
            player?.clearMediaItems()
            player?.release()
            player = null
        }
    }
```

MediaCodecAudioRenderer: Audio sink error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$UnexpectedDiscontinuityException: Unexpected audio track timestamp discontinuity: expected 1000001184217, got 1000001391224

Comment: you just need to update the exoplayer latest version from pub.dev